# Which text asserts that "An assembly with no minority/opposition should be dissolved"?

Tags: ancient-history, ancient-rome, political-history, ancient-greece

[This](https://ibb.co/GP20Ghb) 19th century Jewish work, section 20 of Benjamin Aryeh Hakohen Weiss's "Even Yekarah”, refers to an ancient gentile text (this usually means Ancient Greece, but not necessarily) which specifies that when the state government has no minority/opposition members, it should be dissolved and reappointed because of the importance of opposition. Can anyone help me identify the ancient text in question?